# Weak convergence implies boundedness in norm vector space?

Tags: convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

I saw some proves here relying on "uniform boundedness", but "uniform boundedness" is aplly to complete spaces("Baire thorem").

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: Weak convergence implies boundedness in norm vector space?I wanted to mentiond that I saw some proves here but I don't think them correct because of completeness.

Comment: This might help? http://math.stackexchange.com/a/695469/27978

Comment: No because that's again a proof that using "uniform boundedness" which is realy working in that case because the space Lp is complete.

Comment: Read the last line of the answer. The point is that the dual is always complete.

Comment: thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You are very welcome, good luck!